# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException MS-Sql Server

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate for fetch data from ms-sql server database .I am using below query to retrieve data from table as:

```
"select tw.datestr, Round (tw.s1n301Kwh,0)  
from Tower_3_EB_kwh tw 
order by tw.datestr DESC"
```

But I got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: **Tower_3_EB_kwh** is not mapped [select tw.datestr, Round (tw.s1n301Kwh,0) from Tower_3_EB_kwh tw order by tw.datestr DESC]

I am using hibernate code to fetch data from table as:

```
String queryString = "select tw.datestr, Round (tw."+columnName.toLowerCase()+"Kwh"+",0)  
   from "+"Tower_"+blockName.substring(blockName.length() - 1)+"_EB_kwh tw 
   order by tw.datestr DESC";

Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);           
List< "?" >  list = query.setMaxResults(1).getResultList()
```

Can anyone explain what is issue in query so that i am not enable to fetch data from database .

Comment: Tower_3_EB_kwh is not a valid class name.. please follow the naming convention while writing code

Comment: @Jobin there is need of class name  Tower_3_EB_kwh

Comment: yes. you need a class with the table columns mapped to the class properties.

Comment: @Jobin k i will try thanks

Comment: check this.. http://www.javatpoint.com/steps-to-create-first-hibernate-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got few fundamental problems:

(1) Hibernate Mappings are NOT defined. Hibernate is an ORM (Object to Relational tables Mapping) framework in which you need to clearly specify which Java Class (called as `Entity` class) is mapped to which Relational table (like `Tower_3_EB_kwh`). The mappings can be done either using Annotations (prefer this) or xml files. You can look [here](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/hibernate/hibernate-example/hibernate-annotations-1.html) for a simple example.

(2) Once you are done with the mappings you can use HQL (Hibernate Query Language, it is SQL like syntax, but uses java object/element names instead of table names and column names) to run the basic database queries. But, if you want to run advanced SQL queries which need native database functions (like your ROUND), you need to use `createSQLQuery("sql");`, you can look [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)